# Get variable value from the name(string) combination

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I search the Google for hours, it returned many results, but not I want to achieve.

I use the code for t-sql stored procedure

The code is like that

```
DECLARE @Answer varchar(50), @i1 varchar(5), @Q123 varchar(5)
set @i1= '123'
set @Q123 = '9'
Set @Answer = '@Q'  + @i1
print @Answer
```

I want to print `@Answer = 9`, but the outcome of the code is `@Q123`

How I can get the value of @Q123?

I want to dynamically retrieve `@Q + @i1`, the `@i1` could be `123`, `345` or `678`. The `@Answer` part need get value from  `@Q + @i1`, not always`@Q123`.

---

The reason I want to achieve this result is because the stored procedures receives input `@Q1, @Q2, @Q3, ...` and then  insert new record to a table by these `@Q1, @Q2, @Q3, ...` variables one by one.

I know how to use loop to insert, but I don't know how to get the dynamical variable? Otherwise, I have to write many times insert query.

Comment: How could that possibly output 9? Right before printing you're concatenation two strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like below, remove the `''` single quote from `@Q`. Because of the quote `@Answer` is getting set to `@Q` + `value of @i1` = `@Q123`

```
Set @Answer = @Q  + @i1;
print @Answer;
```

> I want to print @Answer = 9

Then just assign `@Q123` to `@Answer` like below

```
DECLARE @Answer varchar(50), @Q123 varchar(5);
set @Q123 = '9';
Set @Answer = @Q123;
print @Answer;
```

*EDIT:*
Not sure why you want to do it this way but this can be done using dynamic query. Something like below

```
DECLARE @i1 varchar(5);
declare @sql varchar(200);
set @i1= '123';
set @sql = 'DECLARE @Answer varchar(50), @Q123 varchar(5);
           set @Q123 = ''9'';
           Set @Answer = @Q'+ @i1 + '; print @Answer;';
--print @sql;
exec(@sql);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please take a step back and describe what you are really trying to do. What you ask for makes no sense. In order to dynamically retrieve a variable you need to `DECLARE` it first. Why does the variable name have to be dynamic? This makes no sense.

To put it another way, why doesn't this code function the way you want?

```
DECLARE @Answer varchar(50), @i1 varchar(5), @Q varchar(5)
set @i1= '123'
set @Q = '9'
Set @Answer = @Q
print @Answer
```

The code only knows about one variable so why do you have to dynamically name it? All I can suggest is that you use `@i1` to look up a row in a table and get the answer out of there.